# TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration - Python 3

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to loop through sites on Rightmove.co.uk and print out price of listings into an excel spreadsheet. For this final step (printing to excel), i figured I might need a double 'for' loop, however i am getting a TypeError with the zip function.

Please see my code below:

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from xlwt import Workbook, Formula


wb = Workbook()                     # Create workbook
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')    # Create sheet, name Sheet 1 etc.
wb.save('xlwt.example.xls')         # Save the workbook under the name

postcode_list = {"5E2764","5E1682","5E757"} #   Define list of strings referring to each postcode to query


#### Loop through the various postcodes  ####
for url in postcode_list:
    my_url = "https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-to-rent/find.html?searchType=RENT&locationIdentifier=OUTCODE%"+ url +"&insId=1&radius=0.0&minPrice=&maxPrice=&minBedrooms=&maxBedrooms=&displayPropertyType=&maxDaysSinceAdded=&sortByPriceDescending=&_includeLetAgreed=on&primaryDisplayPropertyType=&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=&oldDisplayPropertyType=&oldPrimaryDisplayPropertyType=&letType=&letFurnishType=&houseFlatShare="
    print(my_url)

# Opening connection and grabbing page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()                 # Closes after reading

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"propertyCard-priceValue"})
print(len(containers))      # the number of containers on one page


for container, i in zip(containers, 25):   # loop through all containers
    price_container = container.get_text()
    sheet1.write(i,0,price_container)
    print(price_container)
    wb.save('xlwt.example.xls')
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: What are you intending to do with `zip(containers, 25)`?

Comment: Please explain what `zip(iterable, integer)` is supposed to produce.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `for container, i in enumerate(containers)` instead?

Answer (score 2):

`zip` requires an iterator to loop, `25` is not an iterator.

You probably want to use:

```
for container, i in zip(containers, range(25)):
```

if 25 is the length of the container, then use enumerate:

```
for i, container in enumerate(containers):
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I chose 25 because that is the length of 'containers', given there are 25 listings per page.

Why does range(containers) or len(containers) not work in place of that '25'? I have just tried and I have the error again.

Comment: range(containers) is not valid, range expects numbers as parameters. len(containers) returns just one value, not an iterator, so you need to call range on your value.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Really appreciate you response.

Answer (score 1):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) takes iterables as arguments and produces a tuple by zipping each together. For examples `zip('abc', 'def')` produces `['ad', 'be', 'cf']` (I converted to a list).

It looks like you want want the index of each element in `containers`. In that case you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, container in enumerate(containers):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It now works. I will read into the enumerate function.